# Sum of reciprocals of factorials

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, factorial

Could you help me count this sum:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{9} \frac{1}{n!} $$

I don't think I can use binomial coefficients.

Comment: if you expect the answer as a decimal or a fraction, just use a calculator. If you are looking for the answer in any other form, please specify.

Comment: Just do it? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Well, when I am at home, of course I can use a calculator, but what if I'm at school at I need to calculate a similar sum for larger $n$s?

Comment: @Hagrid see my answer for large $n$'s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} = e-1$

So you can gain an approximation to:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n!}
$$ by using $e-1$, where $k>>9$
 
After a short amount of terms, the difference between the sum and $e-1$ becomes negligible.

Also in general, 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n!} = e \frac{\Gamma(k+1,1)}{k!} - 1
$$
Since $k+1$ is a positive integer, we have that:
$$
\Gamma(k+1,1) = \frac{k!}{e}\sum_{m=0}^{k} \frac{1}{m!}
$$
Which merely shows that the incomplete gamma function serves. 
 
The incomplete gamma function is defined by:
$$
P(a,x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t}t^{a-1}dt
$$
This integral is non-elementary, but at school, you can use MATLAB, Mathematica, or even [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com), to evaluate this integral numerically with the objective of evaluating *larger sums*. But then again, you can just evaluate the sum directly with any of these tools.

Comment: And the error of this approximation is bounded above by $1/(k\cdot k!)$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n!} = e \frac{\Gamma(k+1,1)}{k!} - 1$$

Answer (score 1):

> Well, when I am at home, of course I can use a calculator, but what if I'm at school at I need to calculate a similar sum for larger ns?

Butchered quote ([ref.](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use an approximation.”   Now they have two problems.

If computing is not possible, another approach is to make a definition, e.g. define $$\varphi=\sum_{n=1}^{9} \frac{1}{n!},$$ then work with $\varphi$ instead.  With this method, we don't need to account for error in the subsequent calculations (as there is none).