# Expression for $n+n(n-1)+n(n-1)(n-2)+...+n!$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

I am trying to sum the following series, given n is a positive integer,
$$
n+n(n-1)+n(n-1)(n-2)+...+n!
$$
I think there is a solution, but if not, an approximate result will also be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: You can re-write as $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{k!}{(n-k)!}
$$ This may help with your manipulations.

Comment: You do not really *solve* an expression, but you might be able to simplify it or express it as a closed form

Comment: The sum is just: $n! \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac1{k!}$. For a large enough $n$, a good approximation would be $n! e$

Comment: @OpenBall  and an exact expression is $\lfloor n!\, e\rfloor -1$

Comment: @Henry how do you get that? Can you post an answer? :)

Comment: See [Sum of reciprocals of factorials](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/287959).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: For $n=2$, I get $2+2!=4$ which is not $\lfloor 2!e\rfloor - 2!=3$

Comment: You are correct, I missed the original form.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. All of them are very helpful.

Comment: @OpenBall the approximation is awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Open Ball almost says, you have  $\displaystyle n! \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac1{k!}$ which is almost $n! \, e = \displaystyle n! \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k!}$

The difference is $\displaystyle n! \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac1{k!} = 1+ n! \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac1{k!}$ with the remaining sum being less than $1$

So we can round down and subtract $1$ to give $$\displaystyle n! \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac1{k!} = \lfloor n!\, e\rfloor -1$$

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for $n = 0$: if $n = 0$, then
$$ n! \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac1{k!} = 0, $$
whereas
$$ \lfloor n!\, e\rfloor -1 = 2 - 1 = 1, $$
because the remaining sum
$$ 0! \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} > 1. $$

Comment: @L.F. $0$ is a slightly strange case, but even then you might consider saying $0+0\times(0-1) + 0\times(0-1)  \times(0-2)+ \cdots +0!= 0+0+0+\cdots+1=1$.  The question does not really say whether $0$ leads to an empty sum or whether $n!$ is definitely part of it.  (For $1$ you might also need consider whether first $1$ is the sum is the same as the last $1!$ in the sum.  Both can be considered as special cases.)