# general form of summation $N$ to $N!$

Tags: summation

Is there a general form of summation of $N$ to $N!$? Let's say $N = 5$:

$$5 + (5 \cdot 4) + (5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3) + (5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2) + (5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1)$$

Comment: See the formula section in https://oeis.org/A007526 for some of them.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You are asking for $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \prod\limits_{k=n-i}^n k$?  How is that described by "*summation of $N$ to $N!$*"?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030469/expression-for-nnn-1nn-1n-2-n?noredirect=1&lq=1 isn't this the answer you're looking for? If so this is your answer: $$\displaystyle n! \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac1{k!} = \lfloor n!\, e\rfloor -1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I already wrote in my comment: this question was already answered here [Expression for $n+n(n-1)+n(n-1)(n-2)+...+n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030469/expression-for-nnn-1nn-1n-2-n?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I'll write out the answer from that post here if you just want the answer. For an explanation why it is true look into the aforementioned thread. The closed form for your summation is:

$$n+n \times (n-1) \times...\times2\times1+n!=\displaystyle n! \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac1{k!} = \lfloor n!\, e\rfloor -1$$

For your example ($n=5$) the answer is: $$\lfloor 5!\, e\rfloor -1 = \lfloor 120\times 2.7182818...\rfloor -1 = \lfloor 326.1938\rfloor -1 =326-1=325$$